# Dynamically choosing property from GeoJSON object in leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, mapping

I am trying to dinamically change the property I display on my leaflet map. Here is my code:

```
$("#button_thermal").click(function(){
$.getJSON("physicalProperties.geojson", function(data) {
var geojson2 = L.geoJson(data, {                
style: { color: 'black', fill: true , opacity: 0.1, fillOpacity:1},
onEachFeature: function (feature,layer){

if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 528){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#edf8fb'})
    }
else if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 866){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#bfd3e6'})
    }
else if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 1205){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#9ebcda'})
    }
else if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 1543){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#8c96c6'})
    }
else if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 1881){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#8c6bb1'})
    }
else if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 2200){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#88419d'})
    }
else if (layer.feature.properties.Thermal_Admittance <= 2500){
     layer.setStyle({fillColor :'#6e016b'})
    }
}
});
geojson2.addTo(map)
$("#button_clear").click(function(){map.removeLayer(geojson2)})
});
});
```

How can I dynamically change the property Thermal_Admittance to a different one? When a function is defined, it is easy to add properties which will be chosen when the function is called, but how can I incorporate it within the function defined in onEachFeature?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

You have 2 possible solutions for your case:

- make a function builder
- binding a function

The first solution simply consists in making a function that returns another function, with your property kept in scope from when you build the function:

```js
function buildOnEachFeatureFn(prop) {
  return function (feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties[prop] <= 528) {
      // etc.
    }
  }
}

L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: buildOnEachFeatureFn("Thermal_Admittance")
}
```

The second solution is *somehow* technically similar to the previous, in the sense that it also builds a new function, but using the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) "magic":

```js
function onEachFeatureFn(prop, feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties[prop] <= 528) {
    // etc.
  }
}

L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: onEachFeatureFn.bind(this, "Thermal_Admittance")
}
```